# Version control only specific files / directories

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, dotnetnuke

Is it possible to to source control only parts of a project with TFS / Visual Studio 2013 without cloaking / excluding all other directories (I want to include, not exclude)?

In my scenario, the project is a DNN website. I tried to put the whole website under TFS source control, but that is certainly unnecessary and ended in a mess (a cloaking orgy). There are only rather small parts (e.g. /Portals or /DesktopModules) where I put in work, and I would like to version control only those directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend source controlling the Modules and Skins themselves.

This is done by developing each module or skin in its own VS project. If you haven't checked out my module development templates, do so. They are designed for exactly this scenario http://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/

Comment: Yes I am using your templates for some of the module development and versioning is not an issue with the very helpful templates. Still a number of files remains in the website, e.g. the stuff in portals/. I wonder if I should branch those out into satellite projects, too (not sure if that is even possible) or if there is an easier way to put only certain files / directories of a website under TFS control.

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure on the /portals/ directory.

Comment: I could not find anything smarter than massive cloaking / .tfignore and branching out controls when possible.